# outputting contents of multiple cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have concatenated cell arrays as follows:

data = {5x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}

This command, data{:}, gives me:

```
ans = 

    'MR619_01_XR'
    'MR629_01_XR'
    'MR639_01_XR'
    'MR645_01_XR'
    'MR659_01_XR'


ans = 

    'MR511_01_XR'


ans = 

   Empty cell array: 0-by-1
```

How can I use for loop or another method to output the contents as follows:

```
MR619_01_XR
MR629_01_XR
MR639_01_XR
MR645_01_XR
MR659_01_XR
MR511_01_XR
NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: You're creating a cell array of cell arrays. Note you could also concatenate your cell arrays into a single cell array using `data = [{5x1 cell} {1x1 cell} {0x1 cell}]`

Comment: @Tom you have a mistake there, it should be: `data = {{5x1 cell} {1x1 cell} {0x1 cell}}`. `horzcat` won't work for a non consistent dimension cells.

Comment: @EHB thanks, you're right, it should be `vertcat` in this case, i.e. `data = [{5x1 cell}; {1x1 cell}; {0x1 cell}]`  My point is that concatenating is done with square brackets i.e. `[]`, whereas curly brackets `{}` don't really concatenate, they create a new cell array containing the other cell arrays - that's why the OP was getting the odd output. If all the arrays are definitely one-dimensional (such as in this case) then simple concatenation may be an easier alternative. But that may depend on context and personal preference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp=cellfun(@isempty,data); %Finding where empty elements are
data(temp)={'NULL'};         %Changing those indexes with 'NULL'
req = vertcat(data{:})       %Concatenating vertically

%For your data, it gives:
%req = 

% 'MR619_01_XR'
% 'MR629_01_XR'
% 'MR639_01_XR'
% 'MR645_01_XR'
% 'MR659_01_XR'
% 'MR511_01_XR'
% 'NULL'
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much Sardar_Usama. It worked as expected.